# Jersey Servlet returning 405 even with GET and POST methods defined

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jersey, restful-url

I'm working with Jersey restful API with [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere).

Here is my web.xml

```
    <servlet>
        <description>AtmosphereServlet</description>
        <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.p1</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AdminPanel</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.p2</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/admin/</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AdminPanel</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Now, I have a resource class with `@Path("/register")` and I have defined both `@GET` and `@POST` methods. There is no other class which handles the path `/register` in my entire project.

```
@Path("/register")
public class Register{
    @POST
    public String method1(){
        return "POST";
    }
    @GET
    public String method1(){
        return "GET";
    }
}
```

The url I'm using is `http://129.123.3.3/user/register` and I'm using the POST method in my call.

Inspite of defining both GET and POST methods I'm getting

**HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed**

But, when I remove my serlvet mapping for `AdminPanel` and change the `<url-pattern>` for `AtmosphereServlet` to `/*` instead of `/` the appropriate method is called. But this way I cannot use URLS which are defined in my `AdminPanel` servlet. What am I missing? If this is a problem solely related to `Servlet Mapping` what can be the mapping so that the requests are correctly routed to `/admin` and the other requests are not hampered?

Comment: sub resource locator may help you to solve this problem ,  take a look this : https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html

Comment: Tried that,no change in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a class

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        resources.add(Register.class);
        return resources;
    }
}
```

The your URL will be

```
GET /<context>/webresources/register
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html